# I'm struggling to continue my flow on twilio

Tags: twilio, chatbot, whatsapp

For some reason that I don't know why, instead of continue with the answer that i choose, the bot sends the message that i put to notify a wrong answer, independent of how I answer the question.

I watched and readed the tutorials of twilio, and already searched on youtube how could I resolve this problem, but nothing answered me. I just want to guarantee that my coworkers will be able to use the chat without fails.

Comment: Your question is very vague and this makes it hard to provide a helpful answer. Can you please rework it and link to a detailed tutorial that you followed and also add a screenshot of you flow as well as from the message logs in here?